# Comparison using Merge Sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I am trying to construct a algorithm to compare current item in the array with all items to the right of it.

For ex:

[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]

I want to compare

- 1 to 2, 1 to 3.....1 to 8
- 2 to 3, 2 to 4.....2 to 8
- 3 t0 4, 3 to 5.....3 to 8

I plan to use Merge sort algorithm to do this O(nlogn) time. Am I am thinking this correctly ?

If using the Merge sort is the right way, I also whether the merge step is still linear ?

Let's take an example: we want to merge [1 2] and R = [3 4]

L = [1 2] and R = [3 4]

My modified merge function compares each element in the left sub-array with each item in the right sub-array : 1 vs 3 ; 1 vs 4 ; 2 vs 3 ; 2 vs 4

The above is a slight deviation from classical merge function where the comparison is just between 1st element of each subarrays

Is the time complexity of the modified merge function still : O(n) as we go up the recursion tree towards the root?

Please advise whether I am going in the right direction or whether there is a better algo ?

Comment: Compare the items and do what with the comparison result?

Comment: In your example, the values are increasing. Is this always the case ?

Comment: Which comparison ? <, ≤, =, ≥, <, <> ?

Comment: Numbers don't increase always. The input set can be: [ 100, -20, -50, 40, 500, 20]. I used [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8] in the main thread just as an example.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do. If you want to compare every item in the array with every item to the right of it, it will require n*(n-1) comparisons. That's O(n^2). Merge sort is O(n log n) because it can re-order items and take advantage of the knowledge that subarrays are sorted. Your question doesn't mention whether you're allowed to re-order items.